Putting if-else in environment
I made a tcolorbox based environment that I want to toggle on and off depending upon whether I want to show the solutions or not.
The following code works fine when \boxtoggle is set to 1, but not when 0. I understand that this is because the ifthenelse only works on the begin and end segments of the environment but not the content. How do I make an ifthenelse that straddles across the environment.
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{ifthen}

\newcounter{box} % Initialize box counter
\newcommand{\boxtoggle}{0} % Set \boxtoggle to 0 to disable

\newenvironment{boxer}[1][]
{%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{\boxtoggle}{1}}{%
        \refstepcounter{box}%
        \begin{tcolorbox}[title={\textcolor{white}{\textbf{#1}} \hfill \textcolor{white}{\textbf{Box~\thebox}}}, colback=white, colframe=blue, sharp corners=southwest]%
    }{%
    }%
}
{%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{\boxtoggle}{1}}{%
        \end{tcolorbox}%
    }{%
        % No action when \boxtoggle is not 1
    }%
}

\begin{document}

 
    \begin{boxer}[Text]
    The derivative of $x^2 + 3$ is:
    $$
    2x
    $$
    \end{boxer}
\end{document}


See Why is \[ … \] preferable to $$? and Why is the ifthen package obsolete?

Since you're making a single toggle, you might as well use \if-statements. Below we define \ifboxer that you can set to true (\boxertrue) or false (\boxerfalse, the default) whether you want to set the tcolorbox.

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\newcounter{box} % Initialize box counter
\newif\ifboxer
%\boxerfalse % Don't show a tcolorbox boxer (default)
%\boxertrue % Set a tcolorbox boxer

\NewDocumentEnvironment{boxer}{ O{} +b }{%
  \ifboxer
    \refstepcounter{box}%
    \begin{tcolorbox}[
      title={\textcolor{white}{\textbf{#1}} \hfill \textcolor{white}{\textbf{Box~\thebox}}},
      colback=white,
      colframe=blue,
      sharp corners=southwest
    ]%
      #2
    \end{tcolorbox}%
  \else % \boxerfalse
    #2
  \fi
}

\begin{document}

\begin{boxer}[Text]
  The derivative of $x^2 + 3$ is:
  \[
    2x
  \]
\end{boxer}

\boxertrue

\begin{boxer}[Text]
  The derivative of $x^2 + 3$ is:
  \[
    2x
  \]
\end{boxer}

\end{document}


Thank you. Although I should add that I wanted to hide the content in the else as well. But this works perfectly. Thank you for the links in your comment too.

@RWalser: True. Then just remove #2 within the \else clause.

Incidentally, there is one nuisance here. Any blank line in the environment gives the error: ! Paragraph ended before \environment boxer  was complete. <to be read again> \par. Is there a way to remove this?

@RWalser: ...sorry, use +b, not just b.
